# Python-numpy reading bytes and offset to signed int32

Tags: python, numpy, binary, binaryfiles, byte-shifting

I have an operation to apply in python to more than 10 millions values. My problem is to optimise the actual operation.
I have 2 working methods, numpy and python vanilla.

### Python vanilla operation:

- 1: My raw value is a 4 `byte` data: `b'\x9a#\xe6\x00'` = `[154, 35, 230, 0]` = `[0x9A, 0x23, 0xE6, 0x00]`
- 2: I take the last byte and put it in first: `b'\x00\x9a#\xe6'` = `[0, 154, 35, 230]` = `[0x00, 0x9A, 0x23, 0xE6]`
- 3: I tranform it into a int32 signed value: `-433874432`

---

**File loading:**

```
f = open(path_data, "rb")
while trame := f.read(4):
```

---

**Data operation:**

```
trame = b'\x9a#\xe6\x00'
trame_list = list(trame)  # [154, 35, 230, 0]
trame_list_swap = [trame_list[-1]] + trame_list[:-1]
trame_swap = bytes(trame_list_swap)
result = int.from_bytes(trame_swap, byteorder='little', signed=True)
```

### Numpy operation

---

**File loading:**

```
datas_raw = numpy.fromfile(path_data, dtype="<i4")
# datas_raw = numpy.array([-1708923392, 1639068928, 2024603392, ...])  # len(datas_raw) = 12171264
for i, trame in enumerate(datas_raw):
```

---

**Data operation:**

```
trame = 15082394
tmp = list(trame.tobytes("C"))
tmp.insert(0, tmp.pop())
result = numpy.ndarray(1, "<i", bytes(tmp))[0]
```

It is doing the same processing than vanilla but slower here because of `numpy.ndarray` that is triggered 10 millions times...

### Question

My question is the following:

I would like for numpy version to operate on all value the bitwise operation without `for loop` (that are very slow in python)... Any other solution for the issue is welcome (not closed XY problem...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I use some random data in place of data read from file, which you can do using [`np.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).  Ideally, you would read your bytes into a 1-d array with shape (4*n,) and then reshape to be `(n,4)`.

```py
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
data = rng.integers(-2**31,2**31,size=10000,dtype="i4")
data = data.view("u1").reshape((-1,4))
# Last column first, then other 3
data = data[:,[3,0,1,2]]
# Depending on platform might need to specify byteorder, e.g., "<i4" or ">i4"
ints = np.ascontiguousarray(data).view("i4")
```

This produces values like

```
array([[-1031643175],
       [  267112355],
       [ -640212606],
       ...,
```

This returns an array with shape (n,1) of signed integers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
My variable `datas_raw` is `numpy.array([-1708923392, 1639068928, 2024603392, ...])`
To get the list of list of 4 int8, I have to apply `list(trame.tobytes("C"))` but how to do it without for loop? Your answer is usefull but I did not match with inputs...

Comment: I changed the answer to reflect your input data structure.  All you need is a `view` to make it bytes, then the pivot, then the second view.

Comment: Wow! It seems it is exactly what i needed! I test it and if ok full upvote your answer! Thank you

Comment: The process is now 80x faster, thank you!